# Who gets fractional sales tax?

Tags: united-states, calculation, sales-tax

A 7% sales tax on an item costing $10.00 would be 70¢. On $9.99, it would come to 69.93¢, but the customer still pays 70¢. Where does that 0.07 of a cent go?

Put another way, a hundred $10 transactions (totaling $1,000) would have $70 sales tax (100 × 70¢). The total tax on a hundred $9.99 transactions ($999) would also come to $70 collectively paid by the customers, but 7% of $999 is $69.93. Does the business pocket that 7¢, or does the government get it?

Edit: I did some math. Assuming each transaction only includes a few items (as low as 4 in the highest-taxed region of California), and each item is priced at a penny under any dollar amount, the tax collected is **always** rounded up.

For instance, a local coffee shop averaging a modest 200 cups per day at *.99 would overcollect annually by a rounding error of `tax rate × 1¢ × 200 × 365`, or an extra $29.20 with 4% tax, $51.10 with 7% tax, etc.—it would never “balance out” even if people bought them seven at a time. Who keeps that extra amount?

Comment: It's rounded off to cents. Rounded down. iIRC, so there is no extra; the government just loses a fraction of a cent of tax on that sale.

Comment: @keshlam Sales tax isn’t rounded *down*, but rounded to the *nearest* cent; 7% tax on $9.99 (or anything down to $9.93) would be 7¢, not 6. So a repeat customer in the example would lose out to that rounding error. Who benefits?

Comment: Ah. Correction appreciated. But as others have said, I think that makes the average error zero unless people are deliberately setting prices to skew it. I'm also thinking that this is not actually a personal finance question, which means it may get closed.

Comment: It is indeed not a personal finance question, but it *is* a money question. Is there a better SE for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, back when I had to look up the sales tax at the pizza place I worked at, the tax was rounded up. Back then the sales tax was 5% so it was possible to also calculate it in your head.

For example if the total was $1.00 the tax at 5% was $0.05. But if the total was $1.01 the tax was $0.06.

In my experience the tax was only calculated on the end of the entire transaction, not on each individual line.

It is possible that some jurisdictions do it differently, but I just checked and the state I worked retail still rounds up.

The decision is based on the taxing authority for the applicable jurisdiction. It can get complex because the tax rate in a place like a grocery store can have multiple tax rates. It is also possible that the store has to send money to both a state and a local government.

In the end the store will send all the tax money collected as a tax to some government agency. At the end of the day the manual cash register we used decades ago would tell us how much money in the drawer was tax. These totals were recorded by the manager as part of the end of day duties.

Comment: Hm, if it’s always rounded *up*, then the total tax charged would *always* be higher than the actual percentage of total sales… if that wound up being, say, 5.3% of total sales, from the sound of it the overage was sent to the government. Which, it sounds like, is up to regional tax law.

Answer (score 5):

The tax is usually calculated per receipt, and rounded to the nearest cent. The business remits all the taxes collected.

Rounding up and down averages out over multiple purchases, so in the long term no one is harmed.

For example, if an item is priced at 0.99 and the tax rate is 7% - a tax for a purchase of a single item would be 0.0693, i.e.: 0.07.

But if you buy 10 of these 0.99 items in a single transaction, you've spent 9.90, and the calculated tax would be 0.693, i.e.: 0.69.

In the first example 0.0017 was added, in the second: 0.003 was removed. That's how these average out in the end.

In reality, rounding rules may differ between jurisdictions. Tax rates may differ as well, so the overall math may be even more complex if you're trying to chase fractionals between transactions.

Comment: If all prices end in `.99`, and all transactions include only a few items, then it certainly would *not* average out; the tax collected includes an extra fraction of a cent **per item**. After hundreds of sales per day, at the end of the year the total tax collected would be tens of dollars over the rate. For instance, a coffee shop selling 300 cups of coffee per day, even selling up to 7 cups per transaction, at **any** price ending with `.99` ,  would overcollect a 7% sales tax by an extra $76.65 annually. So what happens to that $70+ rounding error?

Comment: @Frungi It just means the effective rate doesn't exactly match the stated tax rate, the actual collected goes to the government. Whether prices ending in .99 results in rounding up or down on sales tax will depend on the tax rate. There are certain situations where a store might have a larger disparity between effective and stated sales tax rates due to a large percentage of their transactions being at a certain price, but for the people paying the sales tax (consumers), the rounding averages out.

Comment: @HartCO That seems like a pretty definitive answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Frungi tax is calculated per receipt, not per item

Comment: @littleadv I don’t think I said anything to the contrary. I just said it makes no difference to the calculation in the conditions specified (remember, I said 7 or fewer at 7%). E.g., with a 5% rate, the result and the rounding error on up to ten items separately or together comes out the same: a half penny. Or 7 items at 7% (0.49¢), or 8 at 6% (0.48¢), 12 at 4% (also 0.48¢), etc. And several types of businesses, like coffee shops, rarely if ever sell that many items in a single transaction.

Comment: Thanks for adding the bit about how rounding rules can differ, though. Was missing from the answer when I first commented, and it answers the question.

Comment: @Frungi sales tax rules vary by jurisdiction, but in many food is exempt.